# Website redirect inside Repeater

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, repeater

I have been writing a small website that does a check against a database and then creates a bunch of custom buttons that, when clicked on, they redirect to different local IP addresses.

So far I have got the repeater populating and showing the buttons on the site but as much as I try I cannot get the site to redirect or even trigger the on_click event.

Here is what I have so far that is relevant

```
<script runat ="server">
    Sub Button_Click()
        TextBox1.Text = "test"
        Response.Redirect("http://www.musicsystems.com")
    End Sub
</script>
<style>
        .ams-button {
            border: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 60px;
            line-height: 60px;
            margin: .25em;
            margin-left: .5em;
            position: relative;
        }

        .ams-button-edge {
            border: 0;
            float: left;
            height: 60px;
            line-height: 60px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            max-width: 30px;
            min-width: 30px;
            width: 30px;
        }

        .ams-button-left {
            background: url(Content/images/z1/parts/left.png) no-repeat center center;
        }

        .ams-button-middle {
            background: url(Content/images/z1/parts/middle.png) repeat-x center center;
            border: 0;
            float: left;
            height: 60px;
            line-height: 60px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            max-width: 11em;
            min-width: 11em;
            width: 11em;
        }

        .ams-button-right {
            background: url(Content/images/z1/parts/right.png) no-repeat center center;
        }

        .ams-button-text {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            margin: 0 21px;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>

<form id="form1" runat="server" onclick="Button_Click()">
            <asp:Repeater ID="btnlist" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div title="<%#Container.DataItem(1)%>" class="ams-button" >
                        <div class="ams-button-edge ams-button-left"></div>
                        <div class="ams-button-middle" >
                            <div class="ams-button-text" runat="server" ><%#Container.DataItem(0)%></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ams-button-edge ams-button-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </form>
```

Any help from anyone would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure you have valid syntax. Change

```
<script runat ="server">
```

to

```
<script runat="server">
```

Then, you should create a button using the Web Forms Button control. Put this inside the ItemTemplate. You can apply the correct css through the CssClass attribute if you need to.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" Text="Click me" />
```

Also change

```
Sub Button_Click()
```

to

```
Protected Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

This will give it the correct signature so that it can find the event handler.

Comment: thanks for that. I have changed the syntax to match.
The problem with making it as a web form button is that I have no way to set  the format to match the rest of the site that this would be loaded with which uses the above format.

Comment: It works if I change it to a web form button but then I lose the look that we have currently.

Comment: @Wroof That's why I mentioned the [CssClass attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Wroof you can use an image button if you want